# ASP.NET MVC - Redirect to correct membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with buyer and seller functionalities. The buyer and seller 'security' databases are separated and there are different membership providers (with different requirements) for each. The MVC application is broken into areas, with one for buyers and one for sellers (with the addition of some common stuff). Everything is working fine right now as I have different login screens for buyers and sellers. A requirement has changed whereby I need to use the same login screen (and reset password screen) for both buyers and sellers.

Ideally I would like the process to flow as follows:

- Buyer or seller enters their email address and password
- Upon form submission a *common* controller action is called
- Action calls logic to look in buyer table. If this email address is present, redirect to logon action in buyer account controller
- Else, if  email address is present in seller table, redirect to logon action in seller account controller

In theory this should work fine. However, I am aware that it is not possible to redirect  to another action using a POST request.

What I would like to know is:

1. Is there any reason not to change my buyer/seller logon actions to use GET rather than POST given that they will not be called anywhere else in my code? It seems like a hack, but I don't know why...
2. Can you think of a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance,

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a single LoginController. It can have just one `Authorize(string email, string password)` action. Where you do "the split" is by creating a `MembershipProviderFactory` (or whatever you want to name it) that returns an `IMembershipProvider` interface to your controller. The factory can return the correct type of `MembershipProvider` by querying the databases.

```
public class SellerMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
  public bool Authorize(string email, string password)
  {
    // validate seller
  }
}

public class BuyerMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
  public bool Authorize(string email, string, password)
  {
    // validate buyer
  }
}

public class MembershipProviderFactory
{
  public IMembershipProvider Create(string email)
  {
     if(/* email is in seller database*/)
     {
       return new SellerMembershipProvider();
     }
     else
     {
       return new BuyerMembershipProvider();
     }
  }
}

public class LoginController : Controller
{

  private readonly MembershipProviderFactory _providerFactory = new MembershipProviderFactory();
  public ActionResult Authenticate(string email, string password)
  {

    IMembershipProvider provider = _providerFactory.Create(email);
    if(provider.Authorize(email, password))
    {
    return View("MyAccount");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
  }
}
```